# Странная история

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> Странная история, когда в России тебя считают нерусским, а за границей воспринимают как русского.

Странная история - это неполное предложение (пропущено ***это***)?

Answer (score 2):

***СтрАнная история,*** когда в России тебя считают нерусским, а за границей воспринимают как русского.

Лучше считать, что в главном предложении **инверсия**: история — подлежащее, странная — сказуемое. Ударение падает на сказуемое.

Сравнить: *Странно,  когда в России тебя считают нерусским, а за границей воспринимают как русского.*

Примеры инверсии подлежащего и сказуемого: Славные люди — соседи мои! (П.); Удивительное дело сон (Т.);